# Apache Ignite: Global Lock

Tags: ignite

Does ignite provide any method to check if one specified key is locked globaly (in another VM)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there is no out-of-the-box way to do such a check, but you can send a closure to the primary node for the given key and check if it's locked there.
Locally this check can be done via `IgniteCache#isLocalLocked()` method.
On how to send a closure to primary node see this: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/affinity-collocation#collocating-compute-with-data